# Null errors not able to be added to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

*EDIT*The problem lies within my defining a variable **as a null variable**(see the getElementByXpath Area)Please Help this problem*EDIT*

I have a code where the values of a number of input boxes are collected for a calculator. The number of input boxes is decided by the user in a createCalcutalor() function. The input box values are gathered a user-defined getElementByXpath() function(used as var). Then the values are put into an array.

```
var getElementByXpath = function (path) {
return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
};
```

This is needed because of the way I created the text boxes.
Here lies the problem. If a text box is empty, the value produces an error, is not placed in an array, then cleaned(see code below). It instead produces an error, and doesn't allow any more javascript from being executed.

The Code:

```
function grabInputNumbers() {
var inputOne = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input[1]").value;
var inputTwo = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input[2]").value;
var inputThree = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input[3]").value;
var inputFour = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input[4]").value;
var inputFive = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input[5]").value;

var allInputs = [inputOne, inputTwo, inputThree, inputFour, inputFive];

allInputs = allInputs.filter(function() { return true; });

alert(allInputs);
}
```

I am a virtual infant to javascript(I started HTML/CSS/Javascript a month ago),and I am really sorry if this is an asinine question. Any questions on purpose or execution can probably be answered by looking at the site(download for the code: http://www.mediafire.com/download/ftajp5r8uhp5yy7/marshallRogers.zip)
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `filter` you have to return `true` if the value is truthy, right now you're returning `true` for every value, even nulls:

```
allInputs.filter(function(value){ return value; });
```

But this is a bit shorter:

```
allInputs.filter(Boolean);
```

Note that it will remove any falsy values, like empty string, zero, null and any value that casts to false.